# In which order should I write Javascript (Coffeescript) to get code executed in Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

I can generate succesfully ajax-generate my div like this:

View:

```
%table#sir_table.my_table{:data => {'si-id' => "#{@si.id}", 'source' => spectrum_identification_results_url(format: "json") } }
```

spectrum_identification_results.js.coffee:

```
$ ->   
  $("#sir_table").dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    bJQueryUI: true
    bProcessing: true
    bServerSide: true
    sAjaxSource: $('#sir_table').data('source')
```

With the json object and all I manage to generate the datatable serverside processing and ajax.

That's OK . But within the ajax table I create, I need another ajax link to the show action.
The `link_to remote` is formatted like so:

```
link_to( "#{sir.sir_id}", "results/#{sir.id}", :data => {'sir-id' => "#{sir.id}"}, remote: true )
```

and it works alright if I remove `remote: true` and make it work non-ajax ...

This is the javascript I'd like it to trigger:

spectrum_identification_results.js.coffee:

```
$ ->
  $("a[data-sir-id]").click ->
  alert "whassup"
```

But it never gets executed. I think it might be related to rails4 turbolinks gem, that only triggers $(document).ready on the first load, but I am not sure.

Any clue on why is this happening and/or how could I get the javascript executed?

Answer (score 0):

Rails automatically compiles everything in the assets directory into the head application files (e.g. application.js and application.css). I'd check and be sure that in you're application.js you have something like this:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And then everything should work properly if all of your JavaScript and CoffeeScript files are under the "javascripts" directory. If you don't have Sprockets setup correctly (e.g. skipping JavaScript when executing the `rails new` command that generated you're project), then everything won't be compiled properly.

Comment: I think my assets/javascripts/application.js is alright, because I use spectrum_identification_results.js.coffee (same controller) for something else and works alright

Comment: That's probably because you directly reference it in another instance, not wanting for it to passively load as in this instance. Just be sure that Sprockets and CoffeeScript-Rails are set up properly, and everything should work. Try making a blank copy of your project w/ this: `rails new demo -B --skip-keeps -T --no-rc`, and port in your project, where "demo" equals your project name. If you're not using ActiveRecord, stick in `-O` in that command.